# asp page receiving wrong request

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, iis-6

We are running into a very weird problem with out production site. We have a part on the site that will list items 5 at a time. there is also a button to view all at once. When alternating between these buttons sometimes the list will populate with a search that another user is executing at the same time. It is as if that iis is losing track of who is requesting what. If you point the development server to the real database this will not happen. It only happens with multiple users on viewing the site. Any help is greatly appreciated! thanks

Further Info:
We are using asp 2.0 with .net 3.5 . IIS 6 on windows server 2003. The list is being populated via stored procedure from a sql server 2008 database.

Comment: Also, without a lot more information about the architecture and implementation of your site, there's not much we can answer for you. Start with things like how queries are mapped to users.

Answer (score 0):

Is the list coming from the Application object that is shared across multiple users?  That would seem to be the easiest answer that comes to mind using Classic ASP.  In ASP.Net, a static variable could cause this issue as there would be only one instance and so another user could get what was intended for someone else possibly.  You may need to post more details like are you using COM objects for items in the list, types in VBScript or something else?

---

The list is a collection of ADO recordsets or some other data type of which language?  That is still a question that I'd want an answer since there are a few different setups I could picture that I'd want clarified a little.  Classic ASP doesn't depend on the .Net framework but ASP.Net is another story and depending on which you are using these are very different worlds that have left me a little confused in trying to help as while you reference ASP a couple of times in the question, mentioning .Net tends to make me think you are using the technology that succeeded ASP which would be ASP.Net.

Comment: We are using asp 2.0 with .net 3.5 .  IIS 6 on windows server 2003.  The list is being populated via stored procedure from a sql server 2008 database.  Hopefully this helps! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Old now, but it sounds like you may have a static field as a member of your page class.